# Improve performance function

Tags: performance, r

I learn methods of improve performance a code. For study that I wrote function wich return basic descriptive statistic  like a `psych::describe`. I've tried different versions of the loops and at the moment it's all I could do.

**Code**:

```
x <- matrix(rnorm(10*100), nrow=100) # sample data for tests

descStats <- function(x, na.rm = TRUE, trim = NULL, skew = FALSE, byrow = FALSE, digits =     getOption("digits")) {
 if (!is.matrix(x)) x <- as.matrix(x)
 if(byrow) x <- t(x)
 stats <- c("n", "mean", "se", "sd", "median", "min", "max", "range") # descriptive statistics
 if (skew) {
   library(moments)
   stats <- c(stats, "skewness", "kurtosis")
 }
 if (!is.null(trim)) {
   stats <- append(stats, "trimmed", which(stats == "mean"))
   trimmed <- function(x) base::mean(x, trim=trim)
 }
 n <- function(x) length(x)
 range <- function(x) max(x) - min(x)
 mean <- function(x) .Internal(mean(x)) # redefined mean function
 sd <- function(x) sqrt(sum((x - mean(x))^2)/(length(x)-1)) # redefined sd function
 se <- function(x) sqrt(sd(x)/length(x))
 median <- function(x) { # redefined median function
   n <- length(x)
   half <- (n + 1L)%/%2L
   if (n%%2L == 1L) 
     result <- .Internal(sort(x, partial = half))[half]
   else {
     result <- mean(.Internal(sort(x, partial = half + 0L:1L))[half + 0L:1L])
   }
 }
 describe <- function(x, na.rm=FALSE) {
   if (na.rm) x <- x[!is.na(x)]
   result <- vapply(stats, function(fun) eval(call(fun, x)), FUN.VALUE=numeric(1))
   return(result)
 }
 out <- t(vapply(seq_len(ncol(x)), function(i) describe(x[,i], na.rm=na.rm), FUN.VALUE=numeric(length(stats))))
 out <- round(out, digits=digits)
 return(out)
}

print(descStats(x))
##        n       mean    trimmed        se        sd     median       min      max    range
## [1,] 100  0.2524298  0.2763559 0.1024722 1.0500560  0.2842625 -2.905826 3.362598 6.268424
## [2,] 100 -0.1201740 -0.0627668 0.1027268 1.0552801 -0.0614541 -3.071836 2.247063 5.318899
## [3,] 100  0.2074781  0.1946393 0.1006384 1.0128089  0.1928790 -2.312749 2.564297 4.877047
## [4,] 100  0.1088077  0.1127540 0.0935370 0.8749172  0.0864728 -2.757226 2.883687 5.640913
## [5,] 100 -0.2163515 -0.2147170 0.1064167 1.1324524 -0.2836884 -3.431254 2.950466 6.381720
## [6,] 100 -0.0324696 -0.0229878 0.0968330 0.9376630  0.0919468 -2.474992 1.860961 4.335953
## [7,] 100 -0.1497724 -0.1665687 0.1047835 1.0979579 -0.1753578 -2.908781 2.885645 5.794425
## [8,] 100 -0.0197306  0.0101194 0.1030385 1.0616927  0.0615438 -2.711356 2.506423 5.217779
## [9,] 100 -0.0346922 -0.0290022 0.1018726 1.0378033  0.0231049 -2.467852 2.528595 4.996447
## [10,] 100  0.1251403  0.1222156 0.1012441 1.0250359  0.1606492 -2.566209 2.854519 5.420728
```

In each case I compared the elapsed time with `microbenchmaark`. For instance:

```
library(microbenchmark)
bench <- microbenchmark(descStats(x), descStats2(x), times=1000)
print(bench)
boxplot(bench, outline=FALSE)
```

Can anyone be able to offer a more efficient or compact version of the code?

**Update:**

The final version of this function you can see [here](https://raw.github.com/unikum/r-scripts/master/descStats.R).

Comment: I tried `Rprof`. I changed `eval(call)` to `get` but it led to an increase the elapsed time. `sort.int` used by `mean.default` and `median.default`.

Comment: Add `sd <- function(x) sqrt(sum((x - mean(x))^2)/(length(x)-1))` led to reduction the elapsed time of ~ 25%.

Comment: Also improved `median`. I copy part of the original `median` code and replace call `mean` and `sort` with `.Internal`.

Comment: Are you running this function many times, on large objects, or both?

Comment: @Arun: your offer slightly accelerated function - http://wstaw.org/m/2013/01/08/plasma-desktopkMC883.png

Comment: @Joshua Ulrich: I use `microbenchmark(descStats(x), descStats2(x), times=1000)` for compare times and then `boxplot` of the results  `microbenchmark`

Comment: How large is the object `x`?

Comment: @Joshua Ulrich: First row of the code in the question - `x <- matrix(rnorm(10*100), nrow=100)`. This is test example. `X` may be any size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a version that's ~60% faster on your test object, `x` and it always calculates skewness and kurtosis (without the moments package).

```
descStats2 <- function(x, na.rm = TRUE, trim = 0.1, skew = TRUE,
  byrow = FALSE, digits = getOption("digits")) {

  stopifnot(is.matrix(x))
  f <- function(x, na.rm) {
    if(na.rm) x <- x[!is.na(x)]
    n <- length(x)
    s <- numeric(11)
    s[1] <- n
    s[2] <- sum(x)/n
    dev <- x-s[2]
    dev_s2 <- sum(dev^2L)
    s[3] <- mean.default(x, trim=trim)
    s[5] <- sqrt(dev_s2/(n-1))
    s[4] <- sqrt(s[5]/n)
    s[6] <- median.default(x)
    s[7] <- min(x)
    s[8] <- max(x)
    s[9] <- s[8]-s[7]
    s[10] <- (sum(dev^3L)/n) / (dev_s2/n)^1.5
    s[11] <- n * sum(dev^4L) / (dev_s2^2L)
    s
  }
  if(byrow) x <- t(x)
  out <- matrix(0.0, ncol(x), 11, dimnames=list(NULL, c("n", "mean", "trimmed",
    "se", "sd", "median", "min", "max", "range", "skewness", "kurtosis")))
  for(i in 1:ncol(x))
    out[i,] <- f(x[,i], na.rm=na.rm)
  round(out, digits=digits)
}
```

The reason my function is faster is because I avoid a lot of unnecessary function calls, and I store and re-use values I've already calculated (e.g. `dev`, `dev_s2`, `s[5]`, etc.).

```
library(compiler)
ds2c <- cmpfun(descStats2)

library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(descStats(x, skew=TRUE), descStats2(x), ds2c(x),
  order="relative", replications=1000)[,1:5]
#                        test replications elapsed relative user.self
# 3                   ds2c(x)         1000   3.969    1.000     3.920
# 2             descStats2(x)         1000   5.115    1.289     4.984
# 1 descStats(x, skew = TRUE)         1000   8.234    2.075     7.837
identical(descStats(x, skew=TRUE), descStats2(x))
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Also note that `.Internal(mean(x))` faster then `sum(x)/n`.

Comment: @unikum: yes, but `.Internal` calls can change without notice, so they're not as safe.

Comment: @unikum: `.Internal` is not part of the public API, so R-core could change any of those functions without notifying the community. While this is possible, it's not likely. "...they [packages] should not use entry points not declared as API in installed headers nor .Internal() nor .Call() etc calls to base packages. Such usages can cause packages to break at any time, even in patched versions of R." (from the [CRAN Repository Policy](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/policies.html)).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I thought so.