# Delete characters before regular expression (R)

Tags: r, split, stringr

I have a character vector of stock tickers where the ticker name is concatenated to the country in which that ticker is based in the following form: country_name/ticker_name. I am trying to split each string and delete everything from the '/' back, returning a character vector of only the ticker names. Here is an example vector:

```
sample_string <- c('US/SPY', 'US/AOL', 'US/MTC', 'US/PHA', 'US/PZI',
                   'US/AOL', 'US/BRCM')
```

My initial thought would be to use the stringr library. I don't have really any experience with that package, but here is what I was trying:

```
library(stringr)
split_string <- str_split(sample_string, '/')
```

But I was unsure how to return only the second element of each list as a single vector.

How would I do this over a large character vector (~105 million entries)?

Comment: There are many ways to achieve this. For instance `sub(".*/(.*)", "\\1", sample_string)` OR `sub(".*/", "", sample_string)`, etc. Or maybe this will be faster because avoiding regex `data.table::tstrsplit(sample_string, "/", fixed = TRUE)[[2]]`

Comment: Are the '.*/(.*)' acting as pointers here?

Comment: It means "*match everything before the back slash (including) and capture everything after it*". Then `\\1` tells `sub` to return the captured group. Though I think it's over-complecation in this case. The other two options are probably better/simpler. Either-way, this type of a question was asked many times on SO, you should really try Google if you want to see more regex examples in R. And I recommend this site for future regex testing https://regex101.com/ and this one for tutorials http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: Understood. Thank you for taking the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some benchmark here including all the methods suggested by @David Arenburg, and another method using `str_extract` from `stringr` package.

```
sample_string <- rep(sample_string, 1000000)

library(data.table); library(stringr)
s1 <- function() sub(".*/(.*)", "\\1", sample_string)
s2 <- function() sub(".*/", "", sample_string)
s3 <- function() str_extract(sample_string, "(?<=/)(.*)")
s4 <- function() tstrsplit(sample_string, "/", fixed = TRUE)[[2]]

length(sample_string)
# [1] 7000000

identical(s1(), s2())
# [1] TRUE
identical(s1(), s3())
# [1] TRUE
identical(s1(), s4())
# [1] TRUE

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(s1(), s2(), s3(), s4(), times = 5)
# Unit: seconds
#  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#  s1() 3.916555 3.917370 4.046708 3.923246 3.925184 4.551184     5
#  s2() 3.584694 3.593755 3.726922 3.610284 3.646449 4.199426     5
#  s3() 3.051398 3.062237 3.354410 3.138080 3.722347 3.797985     5
#  s4() 1.908283 1.964223 2.349522 2.117521 2.760612 2.996971     5
```

The `tstrsplit` method is the fastest.

**Update**:

Add another method from @Frank, this comparison is not strictly accurate which depends on the actual data, if there is a lot of duplicated cases as the `sample_string` is produced above, the advantage is quite obvious:

```
s5 <- function() setDT(list(sample_string))[, v := tstrsplit(V1, "/", fixed = TRUE)[[2]], by=V1]$v

identical(s1(), s5())
# [1] TRUE

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(s1(), s2(), s3(), s4(), s5(), times = 5)
# Unit: milliseconds
#  expr        min       lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#  s1() 3905.97703 3913.264 3922.8540 3913.4035 3932.2680 3949.3575     5
#  s2() 3568.63504 3576.755 3713.7230 3660.5570 3740.8252 4021.8426     5
#  s3() 3029.66877 3032.898 3061.0584 3052.6937 3086.9714 3103.0604     5
#  s4() 1322.42430 1679.475 1985.5440 1801.9054 1857.8056 3266.1101     5
#  s5()   82.71379  101.899  177.8306  121.6682  209.0579  373.8141     5
```

Comment: Length of the sample is nice, but why not just show the code to make it?

Comment: @Frank I repeated the sample_string from OP by 1 million times. Added to the answer.

Comment: Ok. Abusing the large number of repeated values ... `s5 <- function() setDT(list(sample_string))[, v := tstrsplit(V1, "/", fixed = TRUE)[[2]], by=V1]$v` Might be relevant for the OP as well, since they have AOL twice. It tests as identical with s4 and 10x-ish faster.

Comment: @Frank. That's blazingly fast. Never thought about that. Does that mean if it is splitting on a key variable, it only splits it once for every group?

Comment: It's doing something similar to `s6 <- function() ave(sample_string, sample_string, FUN = function(s) sub(".*/(.*)", "\\1", s[1L]))`, so yeah, it only needs to split each distinct string value once (rather than once per appearance in the full vector).

Comment: @Frank If that is the case, it will make perfect sense for OP's case. It's very unlikely that he will have 100+million distinct strings like `US/...`.

Answer (score 2):

Some helpful notes about your question: Firstly, there is a `str_split_fixed` function in the `stringr`package which does what you want it to do by calling lapply.

```
library(data.table); library(stringr)
sample_string <- c('US/SPY', 'US/AOL', 'US/MTC', 'US/PHA', 'US/PZI',
                   'US/AOL', 'US/BRCM')
sample_string <- rep(sample_string, 1e5)
split_string <- str_split_fixed(sample_string, '/', 2)[,2]
```

It works by calling `stringi::stri_split_fixed` and is not dissimilar to

```
do.call("c", lapply(str_split(sample_string, '/'),"[[",2))
```

Secondly, another way to think about extracting each second element of the list is by doing exactly what `tstrsplit` is doing internally.

```
transpose(strsplit(sample_string, "/", fixed = T))[[2]]
```

On a total side note, the above should be marginally faster than calling `tstrsplit`. This of course, is probably not worth typing at length but it helps to know what the function does.

```
library(data.table); library(stringr)
s4 <- function() tstrsplit(sample_string, "/", fixed = TRUE)[[2]]
s5 <- function() transpose(strsplit(sample_string, "/", fixed = T))[[2]]

identical(s4(), s5())
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(s4(), s5(), times = 20)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(s4(), s5(), times = 20)
Unit: milliseconds
 expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 s4() 161.0744 193.3611 255.8136 234.9945 271.6811 434.7992    20
 s5() 140.8569 176.5600 233.3570 194.1676 251.7921 420.3431    20
```

Regarding this second method, in short, transposing this list of length 7 million, each with 2 elements will convert your result to a list of length 2, each with 7 million elements. You are then extracting the second element of this list.

Comment: Note: `transpose` is also a function in the data.table package, so might as well just tstrsplit it, eh? Also, transpose itself seems to be written in C.

Comment: @Frank, yes you are right. I edited my answer to reflect that.  What then is the difference attributable to? Function overhead? or is it possible that R's C function is faster at transposing than data.table's C function. I guess I will have to do some exploring later.

Comment: Hm, the difference is small; I wouldn't worry about it. Probably overhead, as you guessed. I'd just use the wrapper (tstrsplit) rather then delving into its  internals for a few extra milliseconds.Similarly, I wouldn't fiddle with `.subset2` or `.Internal(mean(x))` from base, even though those offer much bigger performance improvements http://stackoverflow.com/a/17010701/ and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209427/improve-performance-function#comment19719256_14213913

Comment: Absolutely. I usually just run lapply and go get a snack.

Comment: How to get second element of the code that he already shared by using `do.call("c", lapply(str_split(sample_string, '/'),"[[",2))` is a suitable answer to his second question. I additionally shared another function from that package that does what he wants and explained the rationale behind a third answer. I don't see why any of that it offensive to anyone.